# Sending message from HTML input box using ajax and showing response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

When i load this file on my server and launch the address from my browser
the input field is showing and working but when I enter a new string I dont get a response back.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Sending / retrieving a message with AJAX</h2>
<label for="name">Enter message below:</label><BR>
<input type="text" id="msgID" name="name" onchange="loadDoc()" required minlength="1" size="30">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var newmsg = document.getElementById("msgID").value;
var blob = new Blob([newmsg], {type: 'text/plain'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because the variables`newmsg`, `blob` and `url` doesn't update automatically, you need to get the value from the `loadDoc` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url is not updated onchange. You should update the url with the value from `msgID` and send `XMLHttpRequest` on the new url.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Sending / retrieving a message with AJAX</h2>
<label for="name">Enter message below:</label><BR>
<input type="text" id="msgID" name="name" onchange="loadDoc()" required minlength="1" size="30">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var newmsg = document.getElementById("msgID").value;
  var blob = new Blob([newmsg], {type: 'text/plain'});
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh I had the variables outside the loaddoc() function , thx for pointing that out.